# What's causing my 12V DC power supply to tick around 5-6Hz?

Tags: power-supply

I have [this lamp](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075H39NDL) which runs off of a 12V DC power supply provided. There's a faint ticking sound coming from the power supply, sort of like the sound and volume of a watch tick, but it's happening around 5-6 times per second. What part of the power supply would cause this audible effect? Is it some kind of switching relay for AC rectification? If it helps, this happens whether it's on or off.

Please note I'm not looking for advice on how to dampen the sound, I'm just curious.

Comment: Sounds (ha) very strange and annoying. Have you asked the manufacturer if this is normal?

Comment: I haven't, but a lot of the Amazon reviews report light flickering at the highest brightness around that rate, and one person said this was fixed by replacing the 12V adapter with a higher wattage one.

Comment: Usually sounds at that low a frequency are related to the power supply kicking into protection, so maybe the manufacturer provided an inadequate AC adapter.  That's pure (educated) speculation on my part.

Comment: Possibly helpful answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130588/what-causes-old-power-supplies-to-start-humming

Comment: @ElectricalArchitect I don't think there's anywhere in the _world_ with 5-6 Hz AC power.

Comment: Have you connected the output of the power supply to a scope to see if there's a coinciding spike/dip in voltage? I agree with Spehro, it's probably not providing adequate power.

Comment: @Hearth Of course, but I was thinking that the frequency of a mechanical noise may not be necessarily the same as the power one.

Comment: @ElectricalArchitect Magnetostriction happens at the same frequency as the excitation frequency. I'm not aware of any situation where it could cause lower frequency components, especially not ones that would be audible.